# Python sparse matrix & classifiers

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, svm, sparse-matrix

working with naturally sparse data I would love to use the scipy sparse type (**csr_matrix** for instance). However I am confused when I look at various classifiers on whether they truly support this type or not !

- logistic regression, naive Bayes seem to be working well with it
- as regards SVM classifiers (*sklearn.svm.SVC* for instance) I understand it can only predict on same type it has first fitted (so if I fit on sparse matrix, I can use .predict() and .score() for sparse data), is that correct ?

A second question would be about the pros of using a sparse type (appart for memory storage) : is it improving the speed of the algorithm ? For svm.SVC it doesn't look so, but I am unable to tell for sure, do you know more on that subject ?

I have to add that I am planning on using **cross_val_score** and **GreadSearchCV** to tune and cross-validate on those sparse data, and would love be be sure the functions can support efficiently this sparse type.

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: SVM will also work on sparse vectors. I all scikit-learn classifiers will. Sparse data isn't good or bad, it's just what you have sometimes and doesn't necessarily improve or degrade performance.

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a `scipy-sparse` tag (or something like that) to better focus attention on that submodule.

Comment: Okey ! so I guess sparse data won't improve the calculus of SVC() also, maybe I should first turn to LinearSVM as, right now, the calculus is taking forever just for 3-fold validation ... (more than 3 hours for 6000x13000 matrix)

Comment: If your data is sparse, then using sparse data-structures will improve performance in general. But this is also dependent on what you are actually learning. L1-regularized SVM will result in much sparser support-vectors while L2 won't. Keep in mind, that SVC will be complexity-wise between O^2 and O^3 (in regards to sample-size/rows). LinearSVM will be O^1 i think. Therefore SVC will be very slow for big data. SGDClassifier would be the next step, if LinearSVC is still too slow (at some costs: diagnostics, param-tuning and co,).

Comment: Thanks, LinearSVC with sparse data worked pretty quickly !